# How to make rows in a grid stack without grid-template-row?

Tags: position, row, css-grid, shrink, autogrow

I'm trying to make `.item-1` and `.item-2` stack nicely on top of each other in a grid, just like in this snippet:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.item {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.item-2 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.item-3 {
    grid-column: 3 / 7;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    
    padding: 80px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item item-1">
        item-1
    </div>
    
    <div class="item item-2">
        item-2
    </div>
    
    <div class="item item-3">
        item-3
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a simplified example, and the implementation I'm stuck on has more rows of items in different places.
For example: large item first, or no large item at all.

Which is why `grid-template-rows` seems to be off the table, and I cannot find a way to stack them nicely without.

I've tried many different things, from `grid-auto-rows` to the various `grid-*` and `align-*`, to height and margins set to `auto` and `fit-content`, without success.

Here's the same snippet without `grid-template-rows`, where you can see the default behavior of `.item-1` and `.item-2` being separated / getting the same height:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 10px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.item {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.item-1 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.item-2 {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.item-3 {
    grid-column: 3 / 7;
    grid-row: 1 / 3;
    
    padding: 80px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item item-1">
        item-1
    </div>
    
    <div class="item item-2">
        item-2
    </div>
    
    <div class="item item-3">
        item-3
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an image of the snippets, showing the desired layout: [image]

Comment: I'm not sure if you're simplified examples help explain the question. Maybe you can post something closer to the actual layout so the problem is more apparent.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin thanks for the input. I've added an image now that hopefully makes the problem clearer :)

Comment: Is it possible you can expand on these situations where grid-template-rows is not unsuitable? Could you provide also provide a snippet or image to that effect?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    gap: 10px;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}

.box1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}

.item2 {
    flex: 1;
}

.item3 {
    padding: 80px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" >
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="item" >item 1</div>
        <div class="item item2" >item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item3" >item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    gap: 10px;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 10px;
}

.box1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
}

.item1 {
    flex: 1;
}

.item2 {
    flex: 1;
}

.item3 {
    padding: 80px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" >
    <div class="box1">
        <div class="item item1" >item 1</div>
        <div class="item item2" >item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item item3" >item 3</div>
</div>
```